# cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory

Tags: terminal, compiler-errors, ubuntu-16.04

I was trying to compile my code  in `cpp` (command is g++ ak.cpp , here "ak" is the name of my program)   using terminal in **ubuntu 16.04lts** , but everytime  I got a error of two lines i.e

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o:  no such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status...
```

Comment: The command causing `cannot find crtn.o` is missing. Please add to your question.

Comment: command is "  g++ ak.cpp "

Comment: `libc6-dev` provides `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o` . Please make sure that `libc6-dev, linux-libc-dev, gcc, g++` all are updated / installed.

Comment: al the files which  You  have mentioned here are already  installed ..  yet I am having same problem...